# wp7 contentpresenter - setting content to the same page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, contentpresenter

I use a page (named containerpage) with a `ContentPresenter` (named PageContent) and set its content to a `PhoneApplicationPage` instance (contentpage) in the page's `OnNavigatedTo()` eventhandler. I also have a mainpage with a button "Show Form". When I click on that button, the program navigates to the containerpage, that sets its contentpresenter's content to the contentpage. My problem is: if I click on "show form", then press the back button and click on "show form" again, I get ArgumentException with the text

> "The parameter is incorrect"

on line

```
this.PageContent.Content = contentpage;
```

in the containerpage's `OnNavigatedTo()` eventhandler. I guess this is because I already set another ContentPresenter's Content to this contentpage (because navigating creates a new page), but if this is the problem, how can I unassign my contentpage from the previous ContentPresenter's Content?

Comment: It would be better if you posted your XAML and code-behind code here. And post full exception details.

Comment: you have a page with content with another page inside of that?(PhoneApplicationPAge->contentpresenter->PhoneApplicationPage?)  that seems rather confusing and might not work like you expect...

Answer (score 0):

As decyclone mentioned, your question would be a lot clearer with detailed code.  That said, you might implement `OnNavigatedFrom()` on your conatinerpage and set the `Content` to `null`.

You might want to consider how this design holds up if the app gets tombstoned on containerpage.

Comment: Here is the code for ContentPage(the page that contains the ContentPresenter):

Comment: protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
   this.PageContent = null;
   this.DataContext = null;
   this.Content = null;
}

Comment: protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   string contentID;
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("contentID", out contentID))
   {
      if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["content" + contentID] != null)
      {
         try
         {
            Page page = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["content" + contentID] as Page;
            this.PageContent.Content = page;
         }
         catch (ArgumentException ex)
         {
         }
         UpdateLayout();
      }
   }
}

Comment: No matter what I do, I tried it with StackPanel instance instead of page as ContentPresenter.Content (ContentPresenter instance = this.PageContent), the argumentexception is the same "The parameter is incorrect." when navigating to the ContentPage second time (navigation uri is: "/ContentPage.xaml?contentID=1").  PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[] holds the prepared PhoneApplicationPage instances.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm amazed that setting the `Content` property of one page to be an instance of another page even works! I really would advise against that as a long term solution. If the content of the first page is dynamic based on some condition, then use different `UserControl`s instead.

If the data for the `UserControl` is not persistent between calls to `ShowForm`, then you can just create a new instance each time and then you won't have the re-parenting problem.

If you can elaborate on your application scenario and what you are trying to achieve, then we might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: I set the Content of one page's ContentPresenter control to another page, but no matter what I set here, a page, stackpanel, usercontrol, the exception is the same. The containerpage doesn't change, only the content. I'm using this, because making pages programmatically and then setting them as sources of the PhoneApplicationFrame didn't work (applicationbars were not shown up because of the lack of using NavigationService). So instead I tried to make one empty page with a ContentPresenter, I navigate to it, and change its contents.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using regular page animations? If you have logic that attempts to load these pages into the Content property of the current page, then surely you can just use `this.NavigationService.Navigate(target);` where `target` is the destination?

Comment: No, because my page is set up dynamically, I cannot use an .xaml code for it, just PhoneApplicationPage instance and that is not accepted by Navigate() as parameter.

Comment: Clearly your approach isn't working, and I'm really not surprised because the navigation framework is not intended to be used in this way. Perhaps if you could explain your application in some more detail and explain what you are trying to achieve, then we might be able to provide a good solution for you.